# How to set width for the first column or second?

Tags: css, html-table, multiple-columns

How to set width for the first column or second?

```css
div {
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  </div>
```

Comment: you cannot have different widths

Comment: Use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to have control over the width of each column in a multi-column layout

Comment: If you want to have mutiple column layout with separate contents, use CSS **flex** or **grid**. If you want to separate a single paragraph into multiple columns, you can look at CSS **column-with** property.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter `column-width`, but it only serves to define a kind of `min-width` that determines how many columns there will be by defining the min-width for a single column (see example below where the 120px setting results in 4 columns inside the snippet window). It is often used instead of `column-count`, which defines the amount of columns.

```css
div {
  column-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  </div>
```

But in both cases the width will always be the same for all columns created with one of those two settings.